# In Matlab, Why does the input parser invalidate positional arguments, even when no validation functions are set?

Tags: matlab, validation, input-parameters

I am trying to understand the Matlab `inputParser`, as it seems from previous questions people deem it best practice to use this class for validating inputs to a function. Therefore, I am fooling around with it a little and I've written the following function.

```matlab
function output = inputParseTester(reqArg, varargin)
    parser = inputParser;
    addRequired(parser, 'reqArg')
    addOptional(parser, 'posArg', NaN)
    addParameter(parser, 'kwArg', NaN)

    parse(parser, reqArg, varargin{:})

    reqArg = parser.Results.reqArg;
    posArg = parser.Results.posArg;
    kwArg = parser.Results.kwArg;

    output = {reqArg, posArg, kwArg};
end
```

Given the previous function, why **is** the positional argument accepted when I input a numeric value, but why is `posArg` **not** accepted when it's being input as a `string` or `char` array? I haven't defined any validation function at this point, and I might want `posArg` to be a non-numeric variable, right?

```matlab
>> inputParseTester('arg1', 2, 'kwArg', 2)

ans =

  1×3 cell array

    {'arg1'}    {[2]}    {[2]}

>> inputParseTester('arg1', 'posArg', 'arg2', 'kwArg', 2)

ans =

  1×3 cell array

    {'arg1'}    {'arg2'}    {[2]}

>> inputParseTester('arg1', 'arg2', 'kwArg', 2)
Error using inputParseTester (line 7)
The argument 'arg2' is a string scalar or character vector and does not match any parameter names. It failed validation for the argument 'posArg'.
```

Given this outcome, I'd think that `addOptional` does the same as `addParameter`, except for adding some unwanted and undefined validation. This is probably not the case, so what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While by no means intuitive, you observe the behavior as documented:

> For optional string arguments, specify a validation function. Without
>   a validation function, the input parser interprets a string argument
>   as an invalid parameter name and throws an error.

https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputparser.addoptional.html